# Appending to firewall rules remotely

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, windows-firewall

I have one server (Windows Server 2019) that is hosted remotely. I block RDP, SQL and FTP access via IP address whitelisting. The problem is my home IP address constantly changes.

My hosting provider doesn't have constant serial port access to my server. I have to request it every time, and it's always a little wait. I know it's not the best situation but they've been great to me over the years...I was wondering if there is a program out there that would let me apply new firewall rules remotely? Or any other options?

I block these ports because I am constantly getting intrusion attempts. I can't really afford a hardware firewall right now. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: DynDNS is fairly economical. That would give you a static IP. Ask your ISP - my IP only changes about once every 12 to 15 months.

Comment: My home internet ip address changes, I have a server that has a static ip address, on that server i have windows firewall enabled and have my home IP address whitelisted, but my home ip address changes so I can't connect to my server when that happens. I don't think DynDNS is a solution in this case.

Comment: I was thinking DynDNS for your home if that could be configured.

Comment: “I was wondering if there is a program out there that would let me apply new firewall rules remotely?” - There might be but in my opinion that’s the incorrect solution. The best solution would be to have a VPN server that’s only accessible with certificate authentication. Connect both the client and server to the same VPN, only allow the VPN if you want, you might be able to use OpenSSH capability into the server (again certificate authentication only) and change the firewall rules. Whitelisting IP addressed is a really inefficient solution. OpenSSH is a standard feature in Windows Server 2019